# Exception With Tkinter Callback because loop continues in the background

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

Hi people from the forum,

I'm currently a beginner in python and programming in general so please don't shout on me :) I know I have to much global variable and made a lot of mistake.

I am facing a terrible non ending loop problem that doesn't really affect my tkinter window itself, but when closing it is a shame to see this Exception in tkinter callback problem.

Actually I don't know why my batman variable in Valider() function doesn't end all these loops 
Can someone help me with this one ?

Ps: sorry for French language in the code 
Thanks

Here is the source code:

```
    from tkinter import*
from random import* 
import time 
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

#Initialisation des variables
bonne_reponse=0
mauvaise_reponse=0
nbr_total=0
batman=False
nbr_q=10 # 10 question 

t=10 # t est definit le temps que l'utilisateur a pour repondre a la question



#_______________Fonction qui genere 2 nombres au hasard dans des intervalles differents selon la difficultee choisie__________________________#



def Division ():
    nbr1 = randint (1,9) 
    nbr2 = randint (1,9)
    div=nbr1*nbr2
    calcul_affiche  = ("CALCUL : " + str(div) + "/" + str(nbr2) + " =")
    label1.configure(text=calcul_affiche)
    calcul=nbr1
    return calcul





##### Fonction qui demarre le programme et donc qui lance la barre de progression lors du clic sur "Demarrer". 

def Démarrer():
    global reponse_final
    global batman
    batman=False

    reponse_final=Division()
    start_time=time.time()

    # defini un temps de demarrage car le module time compte le temps depuis 1974
    while batman==False:
        now =t-((time.time())-(start_time))
        root.update()
        #Redefini la valeur de la barre de progression
        wq=(now/t)*100
        progress["value"] = wq
        # Fausse le resultat apres le temps ecoule (avec un calcul improbable) 
        if wq<=0:
            batman=True
    if batman==True:
        Valider()



##### Fonction de validation

def Valider(): 
    global bonne_reponse
    global mauvaise_reponse
    global nbr_total
    global batman 
    utilisateur_reponse=entryWidget.get() #recupere la valeur de la boite d'entree
    entryWidget.delete(0, END) #supprime ce qu'il y a dans la barre d'entree
    # empeche l'utlisateur d'entrer des lettres dans la boite d'entrée 
    batman=True 
    try:  
        if reponse_final != int(utilisateur_reponse):
            titre="Réponse"
            bon_rep=str("Mauvaise réponse ! La bonne réponse était: "+str(reponse_final))
            messagebox.showinfo(titre, bon_rep)
            mauvaise_reponse+=1
            nbr_total+=1

        elif reponse_final== int(utilisateur_reponse):
            #messagebox.showinfo("Réponse", "Bonne réponse!")
            bonne_reponse+=1
            nbr_total+=1
    except:
        messagebox.showerror("Boite d'entrée", "Temps ecoulé ou Entrez uniquement des nombres")
        mauvaise_reponse+=1
        nbr_total+=1
    #on arrete le jeux lorsque le nombre de question souhaité est atteint   
    if nbr_total==nbr_q:
        exitnote()   
    Démarrer()




######################Création fenetre principale Tkinter "root" ###################

root = Tk()
root.title("Calcul Mental")
root.configure(bg="gainsboro")
root["padx"] = 60
root["pady"] = 40

# On definit un style et un theme pour les widgets
s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('clam')


# Creation du label correspondant a la consigne en debut de page
consigne= ("Cliquez sur démarrer pour commencer. Un nombre illimité de calculs va vous être proposé.")
instructions = ttk.Label(root, text=consigne)
instructions.pack()

label_trait4= ttk.Label(root, text="--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
label_trait4.pack()

# Création de la barre de progression
s.configure("blue.Horizontal.TProgressbar", foreground='aquamarine3', background='aquamarine3')
progress = ttk.Progressbar(root, style="blue.Horizontal.TProgressbar", orient="horizontal", length=500, mode="determinate")
progress["maximum"] = 100
progress.pack()


### Création d'une boite de texte pour un label texte et la boite d'entree 
text_boite= Frame(root)

# Création du label de calcul 
label1 = ttk.Label(text_boite, background="white", width=15)
label1["text"] = ""
label1.pack(side=LEFT)


# Création d'un Entry Widget dans text_boite
entryWidget = ttk.Entry(text_boite)
entryWidget['width'] = 50
entryWidget.pack(side=RIGHT)

text_boite.pack()


# Bouton valider
root.bind("<Return>", lambda event: Valider())

btn_valider = ttk.Button(root, text="Valider", command=Valider)
# fait en sorte que quand l'utilisateur appui sur la touche entrer ca lance la fonction valider. 


# On rend inutilisable le bouton demarrer apres le 1er clic
def btndemarrer():
    btn_démarrer.config(state=DISABLED)
    instructions.destroy()
    Démarrer()

btn_démarrer = ttk.Button(root, text="Démarrer", command = btndemarrer)
btn_démarrer.pack()

# Affiche la note dans une boite et detruit la fenetre
def exitnote():
    global batman
    batman=True
    try:
        note=(bonne_reponse*20/nbr_total)
        w=("Votre note est de "+str(note)+"/20.0 ")
        messagebox.showinfo("Voici votre note",str(w))
        root.destroy()

    # Si note n'est pas definit car l'utilisateur n'a pas encore appuye sur Entrer, on affiche le message suivant:
    except:  
        messagebox.showinfo("DEVNOTE","Je respecte votre choix mais vous n'avez meme pas essayé.")
        root.destroy()

btn_valider.pack()
btn_arret = ttk.Button(root, text="Arrêt", command=exitnote)
btn_arret.pack()

# On lance la boucle Tkinter qui s'interompt lors de la fermeture de la fenetre 
root.mainloop()
```

Here is the exception :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Thierry\Google Drive\Calcul_Mentalsimple.py", line 145, in <lambda>
    root.bind("<Return>", lambda event: Valider())
  File "C:\Users\Thierry\Google Drive\Calcul_Mentalsimple.py", line 94, in Valider
    Démarrer()
  File "C:\Users\Thierry\Google Drive\Calcul_Mentalsimple.py", line 55, in Démarrer
    progress["value"] = wq
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1275, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1268, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1259, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".59022192"
```

Comment: Consider adding the code to the question itself, not adding a link to it!

Comment: When I click on the link for the code I get a page that says "no preview available" and asks if I want to download it or pick an app to view it. A lot of people (myself included) will think there's a chance you've hidden some sort of malicious code you are trying to trick us into running. I doubt that's your intent, but that's what it _seems_ like.

Comment: There's a lot of code in that script, that's probably the reason why the OP dediced not to include it in the question...

Comment: Ok I will try to post it directly here and yes there is a lot of code as I have not split it into different file yet

Comment: I have simplified the code by removing a lot of functions so here it is :) can someone help me then ?

Comment: @Xenomorph: that (lots of code) is why we ask for a MCVE. the OP shouldn't be posting a whole program, but rather just enough code to duplicate the problem.

Comment: What is the actual exception that you get?

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for helping ! I have edit the question with the exception.

Comment: Print wq before this line to see if it contains a valid value for the progressbar-->File "C:\Users\Thierry\Google Drive\Calcul_Mentalsimple.py", line 55, in Démarrer
    progress["value"] = wq

Comment: @CurlyJoe I have print and yeah just at the end before the error message and the value is actually valid :) This is the value : 

71.68775399525961
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)

Answer (score 0):

OK, two things here:

1) Your Valider() function needs no arguments according to your code above so you could just simply bind without using lambda

```
root.bind('<Return>', Valider)
```

2) When the button/return is triggered and your Valider() is called a reference to the triggering event is passed as far as I know (at least in wxPython it's done this way and short googling gave me the same for tkinter).

That means your triggered function, in this case Valider(), has to take care of that reference as well. According to this your Valider() definition should look like this:

```
def Valider(event=None):
```

Defining your Valider() this way handles an incoming reference to an event that triggered the function but gives you the possibility to call the function directly using

```
Valider()
```

as the event parameter has a default value set as *None*

Hope that helps.
Greetz :-)

Comment: Yes It surely works Thanks! :)  but does not solve the main problem thought :( actually the progress["value"] = wq error happen the number of time I press on Valider while wq is not equal to 0  meaning The loop is still running in the background, I don't understand why batman in Valider do not kill it ?

Comment: Do you still have the same exception as before?

Comment: Additionally according to the code above you are missing `global progress` in your Demarrer() function.

Comment: Yes the same Exception not in lambda Valider() of course only in Valider() now. But progress["value"] is how you set the value for the progress bar I can't see how it can be a global ? But still I have tried and still same error, still having some infinite loop problem here :(

Comment: If the loop is doing background work you should move it to a separate thread (see your other question I answered earlier today)

Right now I don't fully understand what your code/UI does, maybe it could help if you update the question with the code you currently have and translate the describing comments to english so that I have a chance to get an idea of what you are trying to do.

Regards